# What happens when a fault occurs during stack unwinding on Windows?

Tags: windows, exception, seh

What happens when a fault occurs during the SEH [stack unwinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exception-handling-x64) on Windows? For example, if the unwind info is corrupted or incorrect, or the stack has been overwritten with invalid data, and a GP fault occurs during the unwind process?

Is the diagnostic dialog still presented to the user or is there a different behavior in this case?

Comment: program in this case fail handle exception. so it crashed and terminated